# Breakpad process inspection fails

Tags: cocoa, google-breakpad

I'm using [Breakpad](http://code.google.com/p/google-breakpad) to send error reports when my app crashes.

Now I tried to follow the wiki but the information there is somewhat lacking. I just can't figure out what to do with the generated symbol dump files.

I found this [tutorial](http://www.reitshamer.com/2009/09/using-breakpad-on-mac-os-x-10-6) but it doesn't mention those dump files at all.

And when I include the Breakpad framework in my app, create a breakpad instance and then crash the app the console reads

`com.apple.launchd.peruser.501[146] Inspection of crashed process failed`

What I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently there is a problem with the Breakpad build process.

I rebuilt the framework with "valid architectures" set to only "i386" (i only need it for 10.6 and above) and voilà... it worked.

Comment: What version of Breakpad are you using?

Comment: That's interesting, Breakpad should work fine on x86-64. I don't use the framework though, so I probably haven't hit the same issues.